# Python socket - invalid literal for int() with base10:

Tags: python, sockets, buffer

I have a myserver.py file which is listening for connections.

```
import socket

HEADERSIZE = 10 # constant header size

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1240))
s.listen(5)
```

If any are accepted it sends back a message. The message consists of bytes of a string(The written message), encoded with utf-8 and it also includes a buffer header with the value of 10.

```
while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(address)

    msg = "Welcome to the server!"
    msg = f"{len(msg):<{HEADERSIZE}}" + msg

    clientsocket.send(bytes("Welcome to the server!", "utf-8"))
```

myserver.py does not produce any errors.

My second file is the 'client' that connects to myserver.py. This file is called client.py.

```
import socket

HEADERSIZE = 10

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1240))


while True:

    full_msg = ""
    new_msg = True
    while True:
        msg = s.recv(16) # This is the message that myserver.py sends. 16 is the buffer size.
        if new_msg:
            print(f'New message length: {msg[:HEADERSIZE]}')
            msglen = int(msg[:HEADERSIZE])
            new_msg = False

        full_msg += msg.decode("utf-8")

        if len(full_msg) - HEADERSIZE == msglen:
            print("full msg recvd")
            print(full_msg[HEADERSIZE:])
            new_msg = True
            full_msg = ""

    print(full_msg)
```

When I try to run client.py it comes back with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 17, in <module>
    msglen = int(msg[:HEADERSIZE])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'Welcome to'
```

It's like the message is not buffering and instead is trying to send everything at once. I don't know what is going on here.

Comment: `clientsocket.send(bytes("Welcome to the server!", "utf-8"))` doesn't send `msg`.

Comment: That should be `clientsocket.send(bytes(msg, "utf-8"))`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much! This indeed solves the problem.